# Is using Android_ID allowed for advertising purpose?

Tags: android, google-play-services

As per Google Play Store policies
'Beginning August 1st 2014, all updates and new apps uploaded to the Play Store must use the advertising ID (when available on a device) in lieu of any other device identifiers for any advertising purposes'

We have been using Secure.ANDROID_ID in past for advertising purpose. App is now updated to use ADVERTISER ID from Google Play Services. But some devices have custom Android OS without Google Play Services. Is it allowed to use ANDROID_ID in these cases ??

Our major concern is if my App is using ANDROID_ID in code as fallback mechanism when Google Play Services is not available, is it possible PlayStore will reject our App ??

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific section on the documentation that talks about fallbacks.
Check the docs https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248

> Q: What happens if a device I’m targeting does not have an advertising ID?
>
> A: When an advertising ID is not present, you may fall back to using a persistent or proprietary identifier, provided you have presented the user with a privacy policy and handle the data in accordance with the Developer Terms, including all applicable privacy laws in the areas you make your app available.